# BoA is saying my Washington State immigrant relief fund (Covid19) check is suspicious. What can I do?

Tags: banking

I got a covid 19 help check from the fund mentioned in the title.
I deposited it to my account via Bank of America ATM.

2 days later, my bank said that the check was a suspicious transaction and that they closed my account for an unlimited period of time.

I objected, I talked to Sube many times, I talked to the Risk department more than 10 times.

I requested that the current check be returned to me.
They said that the check would not be sent back to me, but to the organization that issued the check.

not sent

Now the 90 days I was told have passed, you can no longer get the money you deserve.
We came here as a family fleeing the ukraine war, but a new legal battle has begun for us.

Please we need your advice.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What country are you in? What's BOF? What's Sube? Who gave you a covid 19 help check? You said you got it "like everyone else", but I never got any such checks, so... not everyone?

Comment: Bof  Bank of America,  Wa immigrant relief fund who is the applied form 2022 can get .. (so sorry for my not enough language )

Comment: Washington State

Comment: I hope I've gotten the edits right. I couldn't clarify "Sube" since I have absolutely no idea who or what that refers to.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 9):

In the US, checks *do* usually time out if not successfully deposited within 90 days. So yes, at this point you almost certainly have to contact the folks running the fund and ask them to issue a replacement check.

I presume you are referring to https://immigrantreliefwa.org/. As their website says, "Call (844) 620-1999 to get help."

Unfortunately the only people who can tell you why Bank of America (usually abbreviated BoA, not BOF) rejected the check as "suspicious" are the staff at Bank of America. If they can't or won't explain, I would suggest you try another bank.

As an immigrant, you may not realize this, but Bank of America has no special relationship with the US government; they are just one of many large commercial banks in the US, and often a smaller bank has better customer service.